# SQL/HQL - Partition By

Tags: sql, hql

Trying to understand Partition By and getting super confused, I have the following data:

```
Name ID Product Date Amount
Jason 1  Car    Jan 2017   $10
Jason 1  Car    Feb 2017   $5
Jason 2  Car    Jan 2017   $50
Jason 2  Car    Feb 2017   $60
Jason 3  House  Jan 2017   $20
Jason 3  House  Feb 2017   $30
```

Would doing:

```
Select Name, ID, Product, Date, Amount,
       **LAG(Amount,1) Over Partition By Name Order by Date**
FROM table
```

give me Jason's correct previous month amount *for the appropriate Product and ID number*?  So, for example at Feb 2017: Jason, ID 1 and Product Car's should give me the amount $5.

OR

Would I need to modify the Partition by to include the Product and ID, such as:

```
Select Name, ID, Product, Date, Amount,
       **LAG(Amount,1) Over Partition By *Name, ID, Product* Order by Date** FROM table'
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, did you mean $10 instead of $5 ?

Comment: Your syntax is not correct.  Your example doesn't make sense.  How about just adding another column to your data specifying what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I myself also came here in search of some understanding of the "partition by" clause. But to answer your question, the new column created would give you the previous row's value. So you don't have to add the other columns (i.e. Product and ID) in to your Partition by clause.
Essentially, you would have your existing 5 columns, plus one (in which contains the row contains the value of the previous row in "amount").